# Data Source name too long error

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA environment, I am trying to copy a specific Column's as "Column1_name","Column_name"from table "Table 1".
When i execute the below code i receive am error as "Data Source name too Long".
Also I am not sure whether my Sql code entered below is right to display column from oracle to excel.

Need hand is debugging this error and query.
Thanks in advance

Code -

```
    Sub data_audit()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim sqlStr As String


strConn = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}; Dbq=; Uid=; Pwd=;"
cn.Open strConn
sqlStr = "SELECT distinct" & Chr(10)
sqlStr = sqlStr & "SAM_ID," & Chr(10)
sqlStr = sqlStr & "DP_QV_Name," & Chr(10)
sqlStr = sqlStr & "From CMS.CMS_SAM_ALL_DATA"
rs.Open sqlStr, strConn <<<<<< error" Missing Expression"
    Sheets("Working").Range("J2:g1047856").ClearContents
    Sheets("Working").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    MsgBox " LOADED!"

    End Sub
```

Comment: I’m not familiar with Oracle, but you are opening and closing your connection string by using double quotes throughout it. Replace interior quotes with singles instead. Also, you have an extra space before your SELECT statement. Remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Joey! Interior quotes are only used as example in the code.

Comment: No way to check but double check if you have the correct connection string. You can check for connection strings [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/).

Comment: I have changed the code above now. I am getting error as missing expression.

Comment: Have you tried typing your SQL command in just 1 line when you save it into variable and without `Chr(10)`?

Comment: Why the need to do the line feeds?  you also have an extra comma.  Why not just use `sqlStr = "SELECT distinct SAM_ID, DP_QV_Name From CMS.CMS_SAM_ALL_DATA"`